# Few questions about initialization and lambda in c++

Tags: c++

I used clang3.3 with netbeans on linux. All in C++11. And I have a question about initialization

```
int main() 
{
   int i(); 
}
```

The following code is compiled but not work properly. This value will not defined by debugger and cannot be printable. I wanted describe int with default value. Instead I can write "int{}" and it will be a perfect default initialization. But I want understand what I wrote here, just want.

Second question. Its about lambda. I want to know how lamda can be described without auto keyword.

```
auto lambda = [&]()mutable->int{};
```

Simple, what I can write here instead auto and compiler will not give me an error ? I just want understand.

Comment: Please don't ask two unrelated questions in a single post.

Comment: One question per question please. Others already have answered the first one, for the second one the answer is "auto is the only solution".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Ad 1.

You've been bitten by the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Basically, C++ grammar causes ambiguities between statements and declarations in certain cases. In such cases, the input is interpreted as a declaration. Since `int i()` can be interpreted as an integer variable definition, or a function declaration, it is interpreted as a declaration of parameterless function `i`, returning `int`.

#### Ad 2.

As for the second question, C++11 Standard `§5.1.2/3` says it all:

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (...) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type* (...)

So, there is no way to refer to it other than using `auto`.

Comment: Oh.. its function declaration.. I forget and confuse it because usually c++ programmers declare them outside function(main) body.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of unusual to encounter local function declaration "in the wild" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thats not a variable default initialization, its a function declaration, thanks to [most-vexing-parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

In a few words, the standard says if an expression can be evaluated as a function declaration, or as something else, it will be evaluated as a function declaration.
In your case, a function `a` without parameters and `int` as return value.

Comment: I believe "most vexing parse" refers to the particular case `A a(B());` where `A` and `B` are types.

Comment: @Zyx2000: It's not a formally defined phrase. The degree of vexation is inherently subjective.